# Why do I get a java.nio.BufferUnderflowException in this Scala

Tags: scala, file-io, bufferunderflowexception

I was trying to do some [scripting in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-as-a-scripting-language), to process some log files:

```
scala> import io.Source
import io.Source

scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> val f = new File(".")
f: java.io.File = .

scala> for (l <- f.listFiles) {
 |   val src = Source.fromFile(l).getLines
 |   println( (0 /: src) { (i, line) => i + 1 } )
 | }
3658
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anon$2.next(BufferedSource.scala:86)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anon$2.next(BufferedSource.scala:74)
        at scala.io.Source$$anon$6.next(Source.scala:307)
        at scala.io.Source$$anon$6.next(Source.scala:301)
        at scala.Iterator$cla...
```

Why do I get this `java.nio.BufferUnderflowException`?

*NOTE - I'm processing 10 log files, each about 1MB in size*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also be interested as to exactly why this is happening but I'd guess it's to do with the fact that `Source` is an object (i.e. a singleton) and how it is gets *transparently* reset. You can fix the problem as follows:

```
for (l <- g.listFiles if !l.isDirectory) {
 | val src = Source.fromFile(l)
 | println( (0 /: src.getLines) { (i, line) => i + 1 } )
 | src.reset
 | }
```

The important bit is the **`reset`** - which should probably be in a `try-finally` block (although the `isDirectory` test is probably useful too)

Answer (score 6):

I got `BufferUnderflowException` exception when I opened a file with the wrong enconding. It contained illegal characters (according to the wrong encoding) and this misleading exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a restatement of Elazar's answer, but you will also get this exception if you try to read a binary file using `scala.io.Source.fromFile`.

I just ran into this (accidentally trying to read a .jpg with `fromFile`) due to a very stupid bug in something I wrote...